# Swift tableViewCell stays selected

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, deselect

When I go selected a cell in my VC and go to another VC, and then back again to the first VC, the cell is still selected. I found some answers here and on the Medium but they didn't work.

I tried this in `didSelectRowAt` but it makes no sense because I will never be able to select a row if I put this at the beginning of the method:

```
tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false)
```

I also found this solution but it didn't work, too:

```
  override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        let selectedRow: IndexPath? = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
        if let selectedRow = selectedRow {
            tableView.deselectRow(at: selectedRow, animated: true)
        }
        else {
            print("no selected rows found")
        }
    }
```

The method above always prints  `no selected rows found`

Comment: How it stays selected? You have some custom view that is shown or only selection style?

Comment: After Selecting the cell in tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: @ the end of the method add tableView.reloadData()

Comment: Why can't you use `cell.selectionStyle = .none` in `cellForRowAt` method.